# How to display the errors of the "Django authentication system" in a template?

Tags: django, templates, django-forms, django-authentication

I use [Django authentication system](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/auth/default/) for my project.
According to the structure of the template, I have to use the form fields individually. This is signup template:

```
<section class="form-container___auth">


<div class="form-container">
  <img src="{% static './images/white-logo-all.png'%}" />

    <p class="title">ثبت نام دانش آموز</p>


    <form class="form" method="post" action="">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <div class="input-group">
            <label for="email">ایمیل</label>
            <input type="email" name="{{ form.email.name }}" id="{{ form.email.id_for_label }}" placeholder="" value="{{ form.email.key }}">
        </div>

    <div class="input-group">
            <label for="email">نام کاربری</label>
            <input type="text" name="{{ form.username.name }}" id="{{ form.username.id_for_label }}" placeholder="" value="{{ form.username.key }}">
        </div>

        <div class="input-group">
            <label for="password">رمز عبور</label>
            <input type="password" name="{{ form.password1.name }}" id="{{ form.password1.id_for_label }}" placeholder="" value="{{ form.password1.key}}">
            
        </div>

        <div class="input-group">
            <label for="password">تکرار رمز عبور</label>
            <input type="password" name="{{ form.password2.name }}" id="{{ form.password2.id_for_label }}" placeholder="" value="{{ form.password2.key}}">
        </div>

        <button type="submit" class="sign">ثبت نام</button>
    </form>
    <div class="social-message">
        <div class="line"></div>
        <p class="message">ورود</p>
        <div class="line"></div>
    </div>
    
    <p class="signup">.اگر حساب کاربری دارید ، وارد سایت شوید
        <a rel="noopener noreferrer" href="{% url 'login' %}" class="">ورود</a>
    </p>
</div>
</section>
```

Django authentication system detects the errors and provides them to you, but I don't know how to display the errors of each field in my template. Now how can display the errors?

Comment: Just like any form: for every field `{{ form.fieldname.errors }}` for the field-specific ones, and `{{ form.non_field_errors }}` fo errors not specific to a field.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `form` is just like any other form, so you can [*render the form manually* <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/topics/forms/#rendering-fields-manually) where for each field, you can access the errors with:

```
{{ form.fieldname.errors }}
```

and for fields not specific to a field, we can use:

```
{{ form.non_field_errors }}
```

You can also take control about rendering the errors by enumerating over the errors with:

```
{% for error in form.fieldname.errors %}
    <li><strong>{{ error|escape }}</strong></li>
{% endfor %}
```